# "npm start" doesn't work tried "resmon" but couldn't find cmd.exe in the resource monitor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, web-deployment, atom-editor

Command given:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

**Error:**

> ```
> added 1898 packages from 703 contributors and audited 1901 packages in 251.115s
>
> 145 packages are looking for funding
>  run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 8 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 4 high)
>  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
> ```

Please check the image attached

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHIg5.png)

Comment: There is no error. You just need to `cd` into the folder by running `cd my-app` and then run `npm run start`

Answer (score 0):

Open package.json in the folder where you've create react app. and check if it contains :

---

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3000 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"   },
```

---

if it does then try running npm start in the folder where the package.json file is situated.